Projection of a 3D vector field and phase portrait
I'm trying to visualize the behaviors of solutions to two similar ODE systems, one with 2 equations and the second one with 3. The additional variable is assumed to be in its steady state for the first system. I'm able to plot a phase portrait with several solutions for the first system and add a vector field. However, I'm having problems with the second system: while the projection of the solutions' trajectories in the 3D phase space is not a problem, I'm struggling with the vector field.
I don't know if it is even possible to do, as in if what I want to do is well-defined. I don't want to assume a specific value for the third variable, either a single number or a value dependent on the other two variables (like a steady state for example). I want its behavior to be governed be a differential equation. Can this be done? If yes, how?
